# Publish Website not working after Visual Studio Update 2 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure, csproj

After installing Visual Studio Update 2 RC, I'm not able to publish my current project to any azure websites or FTP. The strange thing is that, publishing by clicking right to project is not working whereas  web one click to publish toolbar is still working. I created a new project to check whether it would be published and it was okay. There was no problem of publishing a newly created project. It seems like somehow .sln file or .csproj files have corrupted. Is there anyway to fix this? I provide some screenshots to give a better understanding for my problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all I wonder why you are talking for VS Update 2 RC and then tagging with visual-studio-2010 and 2012. Then I would just remove the RC until RTW is available, or use the method that works (the toolbar item you mentioned). Also if there are issues with Visual Studio, the correct site for reporting them is this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio .

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved after installing Update 2 RTM which has been released earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issues some time back and I've discovered that explicitly logging back into to Azure from Visual Studio can help.

From Server Explorer, right click Azure -> 'Connect to Windows Azure...', even if it says you are logged in as correct user log-out and back in.

I've also discovered other publishing\security error can occur when if services are not filtered. I have multiple Azure accounts and subscriptions, again from Server Explorer, right click Azure -> 'Filter Services' and get filter out other subscriptions if you have multiples